# Viewmodel returning no data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvvm, viewmodel

Been trying to follow some online examples, with the aim of moving away from using models for my views, to using viewmodels.

I have a model called 'Property' and i have created a ViewModel called 'PropertyIndexViewModel', which my view is now referencing.

My controller action is:

```
// GET: Property ***TEST***
public async Task<ActionResult> Index1(int? id, PropertyIndexViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Property property = await db.Property.FindAsync(id);
    if (property == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

My view isn't throwing any errors, but it's also not returning the expected data from the model?

Comment: Your action method returns `PropertyIndexViewModel` object. If the method is not being called by passing data for the object then `viewModel`  object will be null.

Comment: You're mixing MVVM and MVC.  Don't do that, you're just needlessly causing yourself problems.  The only time you would want to use MVVM within an ASP.NET MVC application is in the client (with angular or knockout or similar).  It's called ASP.NET MVC and not ASP.NET MVVM for a reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to initialize the view model, fill it with the Property model data and return it.

```
// GET: Property ***TEST***
public async Task<ActionResult> Index1(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Property property = await db.Property.FindAsync(id);
    if (property == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    var viewModel = new PropertyIndexViewModel {
        Prop1 = property.Prop1
        // your stuff
    };

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

In your view you have to specify the model:

```
@model PropertyIndexViewModel
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. I think i had assumed that the mapping would be automatic. I can imagine it get's pretty complex when you have to map large viewmodels! anyway, thanks again for your efforts

Comment: It's automatic if your view display the model, sure, building a view model in a complex scenario could be not so fast and easy.